# Change Volume of apple headphones (cable) via headphone volume does not work?

Tags: macos, audio, headphones, sound-volume

I am using the normal cable Apple headphones and the voluma control works on my iPhone 5S, but not when I plug them into my Mac (Macbook Pro Early 2013, macOS Sierra 10.12.4). If I am not mistaken, they were working some time ago?

Any suggestions how I can fix this, or am I mistaken in that they should be working?

Comment: Have you tried to restart your Mac? Do you have your Mac connected to any other kind of speaker?

Comment: I just restarted and I could change the volume, i.e. see the volume bar on the monitor, but a few seconds later not anymore. No other Speakers connected (no Thunderbolt monitor).